# Overflow: Hidden una duda con menú en el navbar

Tags: html, css, css3, overflow

Buenas tengo el siguiente código HTML se trata de un simple menú.

```css
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;

        }
        nav{
            background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
            overflow: hidden;
            
        }
        .contenedor-links{
            list-style: none;

        }
        nav ul li{
            float: left;
        }
        nav ul li a{
            display: block;
            color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .derecha{
            float: right;
        }
        nav ul li a:hover{
            background-color: chocolate;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="contenedor-links">
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Novedades</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                <li class="derecha"><a href="#">Acerca</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>
```

El selector de etiqueta nav lleva un overflow: hidden, y no comprendo por qué lo necesita, si lo quitas el background-color que lleva no se ve y el fondo del navbar es blanco deduzco que es el color del body sin embargo al llevar la propiedad overflow: hidden, el background que tiene sí que se ve y no comprendo por qué necesita de esa propiedad.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón es que al usar float se pierde el layout del padre. Al aplicar ciertas propiedades, como overflow, lo recupera por necesidad.

Yo te recomiendo utilizar otras técnicas para montar menús con elementos en línea. Por ejemplo puedes convertirlos a inline-block, que tiene más sentido. Te dejo el ejemplo en el snipet. El botón de la derecha te lo dejo con el float.
Usar overflow hidden para recuperar el layout es un problema porque no podrías montar un menú multidimensional, ya que los elementos secundarios quedarían ocultos. Te dejo un ejemplo de un [menú css responsive con submenús](https://elcssar.com/responsive/menu-responsive-css)

Otra opción es usar flex. Todo depende de lo que pretendas conseguir. Por como lo tenías montado creo que encaja mejor el ejemplo que te dejo a continuación.

```css
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;

        }
        nav{
            background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
            
        }
        .contenedor-links{
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 0;
        }
        nav ul li{
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: initial;
        }
        nav ul li a{
            display: block;
            color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .derecha{
            float: right;
        }
        nav ul li a:hover{
            background-color: chocolate;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="contenedor-links">
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Novedades</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                <li class="derecha"><a href="#">Acerca</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>
```